# Webcam not showing on homepage

Tags: javascript, webcam

I have a webcam  working and uploading images to the folder webcam/casema on my website however, the image is not showing when i add the page to the server, if i run the html page in my browser from my desktop it works fine, but when i ipload it, it doesn't display any images, below is my code and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<img id="casema" src="cam_1.jpg">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
setInterval('document.getElementById(\'webcam\casema\').src=\'cam_1.jpg?l=\'+(new   Date).getTime()',5*1000);
```

Comment: yes it is in the folder webcam/casema/cam_1.jpg

Comment: And when you look at the JavaScript console is there any errors? When you look at the net tab is there 500s?

Comment: ok i haven't tried that, i will find a java console

Comment: i am getting the following two errors :

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Comment: GET http://www.casemarine.net/cam_1.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "id" of your <img>: "casema". Now look at what you're using in document.getElementById(): "webcam\casema".

I think your code needs to be:

```
<img id="casema" src="cam_1.jpg">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("casema").src = "/webcam/casema/cam_1.jpg?l=" + (new Date).getTime();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: No problem! You can use whatever form of setInterval that you want, I just like passing an anonymous fashion because it seems cleaner to me than a string of code :)